# How to place the image selected in a BoxLayout with Kivy

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to select an image and place this in a boxlayout with KivyMD FileManager, but it gives lots of errors, like (AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**') when I'm using `self.root.ids.image.source = path` another try with `self.root.ids["image"].source = path` gives me (KeyError: 'image') and `self.ids["image"].source = path` gives AttributeError: ('MyMainApp' object has no attribute 'ids'). This is the python code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.filemanager import MDFileManager
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivymd.toast import toast
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("file.kv")

class MyMainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyMainApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.manager_open = False
        self.file_manager = MDFileManager(
            exit_manager=self.exit_manager,  # function called when the user reaches directory tree root
            select_path=self.select_path,  # function called when selecting a file/directory
            #preview=True,
        )


    def file_manager_open(self):
        self.file_manager.show("/")  # output manager to the screen
        self.manager_open = True

    def select_path(self, path):
        """It will be called when you click on the file name
        or the catalog selection button.

        :type path: str;
        :param path: path to the selected directory or file;
        """

        self.exit_manager()

        toast(path)

    def exit_manager(self, *args):
        """Called when the user reaches the root of the directory tree."""

        self.manager_open = False
        self.file_manager.close()

    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp(title="Noyse Remove").run()
```

The .kv file

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    id: pri
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: 'img/entrada.jpg'
            size: self.width, self.height

    Button:
        text: "Open Archives"
        size_hint: 0.166, 0.075
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .3}
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "second"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
            app.file_manager_open()

<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    id: sec
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .01, .01, .01, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


    BoxLayout:
        id: box
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size: root.width, root.height
        padding: 50
        spacing: 50
        Image:
            id: image
            source: "" # I want to place here the path of image selected
            size:root.width, root.height
            pos_hint: {'x': .1, 'y': .1}



    Slider:
        size_hint: 0.6, 0.1
        min: 0
        max: 100
        on_value: label.text = str(self.value)
        pos_hint:{'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .1}
    Label:
        id: label
        text: "0.0"
        pos_hint:{'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .05}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `image` `id` is defined in the `<SecondWindow>` rule, so that `id` is available from the `ids` in the `SecondWindow` instance. So you must get the instance of `SecondWindow` that is in your `MyMainApp`. You can set the `Image` `source` as:

```
self.root.get_screen('second').ids.image.source = path
```

Assuming that this code is executed in a method of the `MyMainApp`. The `self.root` is the root widget of the `App`, which is the `WindowManager`. The `get_screen('second')` method gets a reference to the `SecondWindow` instance, and the `ids.image` get a refernce to the `Image` instance.